# SED, using variables and in with an array

Tags: bash, sed

What I am trying to do is run the sed on multiple files in the directory Server_Upload, using variables:

```
AB${count}
```

Corresponds, to some variables I made that look like:

```
  echo " AB1 = 2010-10-09Three " 
  echo " AB2 = 2009-3-09Foo " 
  echo " AB3 = Bar "
```

And these correspond to each line which contains a word in *master.ta*, that needs changing in all the text files in Server_Upload.

If you get what I mean... great, I have tried to explain it the best I can, but if you are still miffed I'll give it another go as I found it really hard to convey what I mean.

```
cd Server_Upload
for fl in *.UP; do
     mv $fl $fl.old
     done

count=1
saveIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
array=($(<master.ta))
IFS="$saveIFS"
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    sed "s/$i/AB${count}/g" $fl.old > $fl
    (( count++ ))
done
```

It runs, doesn't give me any errors, but it doesn't do what I want, so any ideas?

Comment: next time, show samples of files that you got. and what your desired output looks like. without explaining what you want using samples, its difficult to say what you are actually doing even if you post your code since your code may be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop should look like this:

```
while read i
  do
  sed "s/$i/AB${count}/g" $fl.old > $fl
  (( count ++ ))
done < master.ta
```

I don't see a reason to use an array or something similar. Does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `sed` command is dependent on `$fl` from inside the first `for` loop, even though the `sed` line is outside the `for` loop.  If you're on a system where `sed` does in-place editing (the `-i` option), you might do:

```
count=1
while read i
  do
  sed -i'.old' -e "s/$i/AB${count}/g" Server_Upload/*.UP
  (( count ++ ))
done < master.ta
```

(This is the entire script, which incorporates Patrick's answer, as well.)  This should substitute the text `ABn` for every occurrence of the text of the `n`th line of `master.ta` in any *.UP file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear to me what you are trying to do, but I believe you want something like:
(untested)

```
do
eval repl=\$AB${count}
...
```

If you have a variable $AB3, and a variable $count, $AB${count} is the concatenation of $AB and $count (so if $AB is empty, it is the same as $count).  You need to use eval to get the value of $AB3.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you move the first `done` statement from where it is to after the second `done`?